"returns a value referencing data owned by the current function" error with string borrowing iterator
With the following code (playground) I get a lifetime error.
use std::{fmt, iter::FusedIterator};

pub trait StrChunkBy {
    fn chunk_by<F>(&self, pred: F) -> ChunkBy<'_, F>
    where
        F: FnMut(char, char) -> bool;
}

impl StrChunkBy for &str {
    #[inline]
    fn chunk_by<F>(&self, pred: F) -> ChunkBy<'_, F>
    where
        F: FnMut(char, char) -> bool,
    {
        ChunkBy::new(self, pred)
    }
}

/// An iterator over str chunks separated by a predicate.
///
/// This struct is created by the [`chunk_by`] method on [str].
///
/// [`chunk_by`]: str::chunk_by
#[must_use = "iterators are lazy and do nothing unless consumed"]
pub struct ChunkBy<'a, P> {
    string: &'a str,
    predicate: P,
}

impl<'a, P> ChunkBy<'a, P> {
    pub fn new(string: &'a str, predicate: P) -> Self {
        ChunkBy { string, predicate }
    }
}

impl<'a, P> Iterator for ChunkBy<'a, P>
where
    P: FnMut(char, char) -> bool,
{
    type Item = &'a str;

    #[inline]
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.string.is_empty() {
            None
        } else {
            let mut len = None;
            let mut left_char = None;
            for (right_index, right_char) in self.string.char_indices() {
                if let Some(left_char) = left_char {
                    if !(self.predicate)(left_char, right_char) {
                        len = Some(right_index);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                left_char = Some(right_char);
            }
            let (head, tail) = self.string.split_at(len.unwrap_or(self.string.len()));
            self.string = tail;
            Some(head)
        }
    }

    #[inline]
    fn size_hint(&self) -> (usize, Option<usize>) {
        if self.string.is_empty() {
            (0, Some(0))
        } else {
            (1, Some(self.string.len()))
        }
    }
}

impl<'a, P> FusedIterator for ChunkBy<'a, P> where P: FnMut(char, char) -> bool {}

impl<'a, P> fmt::Debug for ChunkBy<'a, P> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        f.debug_struct("ChunkBy")
            .field("string", &self.string)
            .finish()
    }
}

// ----------

fn split_numbers<'a>(x: &'a str) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    let mut parts = Vec::new();
    for text in x
        .chunk_by(|c0, c1| c0.is_ascii_alphanumeric() == c1.is_ascii_alphanumeric())
    {
        parts.push(text);
    }
    parts
}

error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing function parameter `x`
  --> src/main.rs:93:5
   |
88 |     for text in x
   |                 - `x` is borrowed here
...
93 |     parts
   |     ^^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

I think it's complaining that text is borrowing ChunkBy::string, and that value will indeed be dropped, even though the string that ChunkBy::string is a reference to lives long enough.
Is there any way to fix this?

The issue is that your chunk_by operates on &&str where you want it to operate on &str.
impl StrChunkBy for &str {
    #[inline]
    fn chunk_by<F>(&self, pred: F) -> ChunkBy<'_, F>
    where
        F: FnMut(char, char) -> bool,
    {
        ChunkBy::new(self, pred)
    }
}

Here self is &str, so &self is &&str. If you change the impl to say
impl StrChunkBy for str

Then it compiles: playground

The way I found this was by switching to a more-fully-qualified syntax in split_numbers, using StrChunkBy::chunk_by(x, ...) instead of x.chunk_by(...).
If you use:
fn split_numbers<'a>(x: &'a str) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    let mut parts = Vec::new();
    for text in StrChunkBy::chunk_by(x, |c0, c1| c0.is_ascii_alphanumeric() == c1.is_ascii_alphanumeric())
    {
        parts.push(text);
    }
    parts
}

You see a more-helpful error:
error[E0277]: the trait bound `str: StrChunkBy` is not satisfied
  --> src/lib.rs:88:38
   |
88 |     for text in StrChunkBy::chunk_by(x, |c0, c1| c0.is_ascii_alphanumeric() == c1.is_ascii_alphanumeric())
   |                 -------------------- ^ the trait `StrChunkBy` is not implemented for `str`

playground

It's not immediately obvious to me how exactly creating the extra borrow (&x) leaks down to the text that gets pushed to parts and causes text to be tied to the new shorter lifetime. Like your ChunkBy struct surely can only hold &str not &&str. So when ChunkBy::new(self, pred) happens, there may be some reborrowing or something that's beyond my knowledge shortening the lifetime.

Ah that makes perfect sense, thanks! And thanks for saying how you found out too - that's very useful.
